# How do I map a range of colors to a range of integers?

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors

**How do I map a range of colors to a range of integers?**

Specifically, I want the slider to go from dark green, to yellow, to red.

The following code only adds shade to the color.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="MotoLens.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MotoLens"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="Black"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ValueToBrushConverter x:Key="ValueToBrushConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Slider x:Name="Slider" Grid.Row="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="200" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBrushConverter}, ConverterParameter=0~200}" 
                TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickPlacement="TopLeft" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ValueConverter:**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var args = parameter as string;
    var minimumInput = int.Parse(args?.Split('~')?[0]);
    var maximumInput = int.Parse(args?.Split('~')?[1]);

    var currentValue = (double)value;
    var colorValue = (int)255 - (currentValue * (COLOR_RANGE_MAX / maximumInput));
    var color = Color.FromArgb(COLOR_RANGE_MAX, 0, System.Convert.ToByte(colorValue), 0);
    return new SolidColorBrush(color);
}
```

**NOTE:**
My memory tells me that I should let the framework do it for me via an animation.
Not sure if it's a color animation or double animation.

**UPDATED via Answer:**

```
namespace MotoLens
{
    class ValueToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        static readonly Color[] _colorTable =
            {
            Color.FromRgb(  0, 255, 255),
            Color.FromRgb(  0, 255,   0),
            Color.FromRgb(255, 255,   0),
            Color.FromRgb(255,   0,   0),
            };

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var args = parameter as string;
            var minimumInput = int.Parse(args.Split('~')[0]);
            var maximumInput = int.Parse(args.Split('~')[1]);

            var currentValue = ((double)value - minimumInput) / (maximumInput - minimumInput);
            var col1 = (int)(currentValue * (_colorTable.Length - 1));
            var col2 = Math.Min(col1 + 1, (_colorTable.Length - 1));

            var t = 1.0 / (_colorTable.Length - 1);
            return new SolidColorBrush(Lerp(_colorTable[col1], _colorTable[col2], (currentValue - t * col1) / t));
        }

        public static Color Lerp(Color col1, Color col2, double t)
        {
            var r = col1.R * (1 - t) + col2.R * t;
            var g = col1.G * (1 - t) + col2.G * t;
            var b = col1.B * (1 - t) + col2.B * t;
            return Color.FromRgb((byte)r, (byte)g, (byte)b);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private static readonly Color[] ColorTable =
    {
        Color.FromRgb(255,   0,   0),
        Color.FromRgb(255, 255,   0),
        Color.FromRgb(  0, 255,   0),
        Color.FromRgb(  0, 255, 255),
        Color.FromRgb(  0,   0, 255),
        Color.FromRgb(255,   0, 255),
        Color.FromRgb(255,   0,   0),
    };

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {           
        var args = parameter as string;
        var minimumInput = int.Parse(args.Split('~')[0]);
        var maximumInput = int.Parse(args.Split('~')[1]);
        var currentValue = ((double)value - minimumInput) / (maximumInput - minimumInput);
        var col1 = (int)(currentValue * (ColorTable.Length-1));
        var col2 = Math.Min(col1+1, (ColorTable.Length-1));
        var t = 1.0 / (ColorTable.Length - 1);
        return new SolidColorBrush(Lerp(ColorTable[col1], ColorTable[col2], (currentValue - t *col1) / t));
    }

    public static Color Lerp(Color col1, Color col2, double t)
    {
        var r = col1.R * (1-t) + col2.R * t;
        var g = col1.G * (1-t) + col2.G * t;
        var b = col1.B * (1-t) + col2.B * t;
        return Color.FromRgb((byte)r, (byte)g, (byte)b);
    }
```

Comment: So has the question been answered satisfactorily? Or are there other requirements? BTW my answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513387/how-to-create-a-color-canvas-for-color-picker-wpf) regarding color pickers might also be of interest in this case, you'd typically use something like the hue bar as the background for a slider.

Comment: Yes. Now I have a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760507/how-can-i-create-a-gauge-i-e-speedometer

Answer (score 0):

You could do something based on my [`ColorExtensions`](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP/Imaging/ColorExtensions.cs) that have a method to convert from HSL or HSV to RGB. Eg.

```
#region FromHsv()
/// <summary>
/// Returns a Color struct based on HSV model.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hue">0..360 range hue</param>
/// <param name="saturation">0..1 range saturation</param>
/// <param name="value">0..1 range value</param>
/// <param name="alpha">0..1 alpha</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Color FromHsv(double hue, double saturation, double value, double alpha = 1.0)
{
    Debug.Assert(hue >= 0);
    Debug.Assert(hue <= 360);

    double chroma = value * saturation;
    double h1 = hue / 60;
    double x = chroma * (1 - Math.Abs(h1 % 2 - 1));
    double m = value - chroma;
    double r1, g1, b1;

    if (h1 < 1)
    {
        r1 = chroma;
        g1 = x;
        b1 = 0;
    }
    else if (h1 < 2)
    {
        r1 = x;
        g1 = chroma;
        b1 = 0;
    }
    else if (h1 < 3)
    {
        r1 = 0;
        g1 = chroma;
        b1 = x;
    }
    else if (h1 < 4)
    {
        r1 = 0;
        g1 = x;
        b1 = chroma;
    }
    else if (h1 < 5)
    {
        r1 = x;
        g1 = 0;
        b1 = chroma;
    }
    else //if (h1 < 6)
    {
        r1 = chroma;
        g1 = 0;
        b1 = x;
    }

    byte r = (byte)(255 * (r1 + m));
    byte g = (byte)(255 * (g1 + m));
    byte b = (byte)(255 * (b1 + m));
    byte a = (byte)(255 * alpha);

    return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
} 
#endregion
```

Example - XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider
        x:Name="HueSlider"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="360"
        StepFrequency="1"
        ValueChanged="HueSlider_ValueChanged" />
    <Rectangle
        x:Name="HueRect"
        Width="400"
        Height="200" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
private void HueSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    HueRect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(
        FromHsv(e.NewValue, 1, 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure to use this in regards to mapping an integer value to a color via min and max.

Comment: HSV model has a hue component that is easier to manipulate to get different colors than RGB. You can call `FromHsv(hue, 1, 1)` for hue values of 0..1 to get different Color values. For int hue values of 0..255 you would call `FromHsv((double)hue / 255, 1, 1)`, but the `Slider` control gives you `double` typed `Value` and not an `int`, so you could use that.

Comment: Actually, scratch that - the range is 0..360, so you don't have to divide anything.