# How can I create a gauge (i.e. speedometer)?

Tags: .net, wpf, geometry

How can I create a gauge (i.e. speedometer)?

Specifically, I am trying to build the image on this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Speedometer-by-Sygic/9WZDNCRFHZF3).

[image]

I am successful at creating a ring. However, now I need to add the ticks to the ring.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="MotoLens.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MotoLens"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="Black"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ValueToBrushConverter x:Key="ValueToBrushConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Ellipse Grid.Row="0" Width="300" Fill="Transparent"  StrokeThickness="10" Stroke="{Binding ElementName=Slider, Path=Background}"  StrokeDashArray="1" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why are you posting the XAML and ValueConverter code from your last question when it has no bearing to this one? In any case I would create two graphics with ticks lit in one and not the other. Put the unlit one in the background and put the lit one in front of it, then create an ArcSegment with the start and end angles set accordingly and use it as an opacity map for the lit graphic.

Comment: I would search for "WPF speedometer" and use one of the answers there, such as https://wpfgauge.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MarkFeldman - I appreciate your help. Can this be done using XAML? Or am I doing this programmatically?

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where I would probably create a custom user control. Give it a couple of dependency properties for number of ticks, starting/ending color etc and generate a list of items for each tick containing the background color and rotation angle. Then render them with an ItemsControl using a Canvas as the ItemsPanel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the past, when I had to create custom pie charts and other various things requiring elliptical shapes and arcs, I've used the `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing` library.  Just add that reference to your project and you'll get access to `Arc`, which will do wonders here.  The exact same thing can be achieved with `Path`, `ArcSegment` and various other components, but I just find it easy to work with `Arc`.  Speaking of adding references... that is one of the reasons things like this are handled in Blend, if you're not already doing that, as it automatically brings in those references.  I made no assumptions here, so that's why I gave the instructions of adding the reference.

So, with that said, here's an example a 10-minute project that shows what you can do:

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="#FF2E2F45">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-120">
            <ed:Arc StartAngle="-120" EndAngle="120" Stretch="None" 
                    Height="300" Width="300" StrokeThickness="20"      
                    StrokeDashArray=".25" Stroke="#FF484D5F"/>
            <ed:Arc StartAngle="-120" EndAngle="-35" Stretch="None" 
                    Height="300" Width="300" StrokeThickness="20"
                    StrokeDashArray=".25" Stroke="Turquoise"/>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,0,0,-50">
            <TextBlock Text="km/h" Foreground="#FF878A9F" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="14"/>
            <TextBlock Text="43" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="110" FontWeight="Light" Margin="0,-25,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It goes without saying that there is a lot of static code going on in there, as far as placement of things, but that was done for the demonstration.  Most of it is not even necessary, based on what the image of that app in the link you've provided shows, but I'm obsessive about detail and wanted the layout to somewhat match your screenshot in the question. I assume you would create a control out of this, so you'd clean it all up and create appropriate bindings.

As far as the circular gradient topic is concerned, I did not bother working on that here, as that's a completely different subject from what you were asking about and more can be found at a different StackOverflow question right over here: [Creating Gradient Brush along a Circular Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839666/creating-gradient-brush-along-a-circular-path)

Comment: Wow... you made it look so easy. Is there any reading material you recommend for building custom controls like this?

Comment: @ScottNimrod Hmm... That's a very good question, because I had the exact same one when I started a couple of years ago. Unfortunately, beyond the very basics of custom controls that you can find in books and on the internet, no one really goes into great detail. I say your best bet is "WPF Control Development Unleashed: Building Advanced user Experiences."  Note that it assumes VERY good knowledge of WPF. Everything else I've come across has fairly generic content you can find on MSDN that just gets you started. The rest is just experience.  Perfect practice makes perfect.