# Colour an RGB cube

Tags: wpf, xaml, rgb

I want to colour the six sides of a cube with the right colours, for example like this:

[image]

How could I do this?

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Viewport3D Name="viewport3D1">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain" Position="6 5 4" 
                               LookDirection="-6 -5 -4">
            </PerspectiveCamera>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <DirectionalLight x:Name="dirLightMain" Direction="-1,-1,-1">
                </DirectionalLight>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D x:Name="MyModel">
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain"
Positions="0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  1 1 0  0 0 1  1 0 1  0 1 1  1 1 1"
TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                        </MeshGeometry3D>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain">
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" 
                                                     EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.0"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" CenterZ="0.5">
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotate" Axis="1 0 0"/>
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
    <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="slider1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="187" 
            Maximum="360"
            Value="{Binding ElementName=rotate, Path=Angle}" 
            ValueChanged="slider1_ValueChanged" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I rearranged your question a bit putting the code at the end (with some extra indenting) and removing the image hyper-link (as the image is already embedded).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in XAML alone but you're going to need to split the cube out into its 6 faces and apply a different texture to each one.

The textures themselves will need to be VisualBrushes containing two linear gradient brushes, one for each axis. My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513387/how-to-create-a-color-canvas-for-color-picker-wpf) should be enough to get you going.

Secondly, if you want to apply a VisualBrush to a mesh geometry then you'll also need to specify texture coordinates, [this page](http://mikestedman.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/3d-visualbrush-and-texturecoordinates.html) contains some details on how to do that.

If you still can't get this to work then post back here and I'll have a crack at it myself.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions:
- replace geometryModel of cube on 6 geometries of planks with colorized materials
- apply image texture for cube